# Are the past continuous and and the past perfect continuous interchangeable in certain contexts?

Tags: past-continuous, past-perfect-continuous

Could you tell me if the past continuous and and the past perfect continuous are interchangeable in certain context? For example:

> Before I moved to the countryside **I was living** in the city for several years.
>
> Before I moved to the countryside **I had been living** in the city for several years.
>
> When I started studying at the university, **I was working** for two years as a construction worker.
>
> When I started studying at the university, **I had been working** for two years as a construction worker.

I can't see any difference between those sentences. Is there any?

Comment: The third sentence doesn't work. _When I started at university_ is a point in time, by which presumably the two years of construction work must have finished. This isn't such a problem with your first sentence, since _before_ is more vague as to timing (but you couldn't say _When I moved to the country I was living in the city_).

Comment: the following resource should help you: https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfectcontinuous.html

Answer (score -1):

No they're not interchangeable. The first one isn't wrong, per se, but feels slightly uncomfortable. The second one is fine. The third one is wrong, and the fourth one is fine.

This is in agreement with reputable [sources](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/past-continuous-or-past-simple)

> Often there is little difference between the past continuous and the
> past simple, except that the past continuous suggests that the
> event(s) were in progress at a time in the past or that they were
> happening as background or temporary events. Whether we choose to use
> the past continuous or past simple often depends on how we see the
> past event(s).

In fact, another [resource](https://ginsengenglish.com/blog/past-perfect-continuous) mentions

> The past perfect progressive shows that an action started in the past
> and continued up to another time or action, also in the past. It does
> not specify if the action continues after that point. This is a very
> uncommon verb form: less than .1% of verbs in spoken English are in
> this form.
>
> Just to be clear, continuous and progressive are just different names
> for this same thing. In some countries, one word is more common, but
> continuous is more common around the world, so we use that!

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect) has a more in-depth discussion of the tense in question

> The present perfect is a grammatical combination of the present tense
> and perfect aspect that is used to express a past event that has
> present consequences.[1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/past-continuous-or-past-simple) The term is used particularly in the context
> of English grammar to refer to forms like "I have finished". The forms
> are present because they use the present tense of the auxiliary verb
> have, and perfect because they use that auxiliary in combination with
> the past participle of the main verb. (Other perfect constructions
> also exist, such as the past perfect: "I had eaten.")
>
> Analogous forms are found in some other languages, and they may also
> be described as present perfect; they often have other names such as
> the German Perfekt, the French passé composé and the Italian passato
> prossimo. They may also have different ranges of usage: in all three
> of the languages just mentioned, the forms in question serve as a
> general past tense, at least for completed actions.
>
> In English, completed actions in many contexts are referred to using
> the simple past verb form rather than the present perfect. English
> also has a present perfect continuous (or present perfect progressive)
> form, which combines present tense with both perfect aspect and
> continuous (progressive) aspect: "I have been eating". The action is
> not necessarily complete; and the same is true of certain uses of the
> basic present perfect when the verb expresses a state or a habitual
> action: "I have lived here for five years."

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/115779)

Comment: Hi. I feel that I have provided an answer to the question? I clearly state that they are not interchangeable.

Comment: Note that both on EL&U and on ELL, the users must explain why and provide research for their answers. Making assertions is not enough. If you back up your information with reliable sources, you'll be fine.

Comment: please note i have revised my answer @fev